# Inquires about node process.send functioning and impact

Tags: node.js, express

These are a couple of conceptual concerns I've got. Node docs state about process.send:

> If Node.js is spawned with an IPC channel, the process.send() method can be used to send messages to the parent process. Messages will be received as a 'message' event on the parent's ChildProcess object.
>
> If Node.js was not spawned with an IPC channel, process.send will be undefined.

What does it mean to be "spawned with an IPC channel" or not, should I care about it or is it something that OS will handle?

Also, reading node docs I got a minimum understanding of what is going in the code below. However, I do not get "running in a fork". Is it meaningful to perform this validation?

```
app.listen(port, () => {
  sendBootStatus("ready");
});

function sendBootStatus(status) {
  // don't send anything if we're not running in a fork
  if (!process.send) {
    return;
  }
  process.send({ boot: status });
}
```

Thanks in advance, happy hollydays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start a child process with [child_process.fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options), code running in such a process can use process.send to send messages to the parent process.

The check is meaningful if you want to run the same module in main/child process, if so you can do

```
if (process.send) {
    // do whatever you need done in child process
} else {
    // this is main process spawn your child process(es) and do other setup
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bdew. Just so I can make a clear picture in my head, I got a question. I don't usually care for the main/child processes. What would be a use case for me to care about it? I usually go about writing my node.js apps without concerning about it.